# webforms How to bind multiple tables to GridView

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, gridview, iqueryable

I did my research, but I can't find a way to connect multiple tables from Entity framework to the GridView control without something between them, but I also didn't stumble upon an answer that said that this can't be done.

I have three tables: Report, ReportType and Client. Each Report has foreign keys (linked to ID properties) to 1 of the ReportTypes, and 1 of the Clients. In table that I'm making, I need to put some columns from Report table, ReportType's Name and Client's Name property.

I'm new to GridView, and I know that Entity is working with IQueryables for when it's getting tables. I know that I can get the ReportTypes and Clients Names like this:

```
List<Report> reports;
using (FinReports_ConceptEntities db = new FinReports_ConceptEntities())
{
    reports = db.Reports.Include(r => r.Client).Include(r => r.ReportType).ToList();
}
```

But in GridView I need to put an exact class name in ItemType property, which means I need to make a new class just for that, and then populate a list of that class, and then link it to GridView, and that class must be an IQueryable, because I need it to be for GridView to be able to have paging and search. And that creates a lot of work if you have multiple GridViews.

**Note** that the GridView I need will just be a list of Reports with no editing, updating or deleting, which, upon a click on a row, will get the user to another page. All reports will link to another page but with another ReportID-like variable in session or address bar.

**Also note** that I'm searching for a solution like this for the sake of code simplicity. I know I can make classes for each GridView that uses multiple tables, that I need, but I also know that this complicates code that I *personaly* think can be done in a shorter fashon. I know that I can simply loop trough a populated list of Reports and store all the data in Table class, but then I'd have to make custom search and paging algorithms.

**Questions**
**1)** Can a GridView be created with ItemType set to Report (or maybe something else that is not a class new class that needs to be created) but in a way that I can include linked-via-foreign-key properties of other tables? I imagine that setting custom colums can have some inpact on that idea.

**2)** What are some other options that I might have missed? Maybe a view?
**3)** How would I do this in MVC? (maybe just a link for a tutorial on this topic. I just need to know the difference between WebForms and MVC in this manner of GridView)

If you already know a link for a tutorial that would help me in this case, please link it in the answer, because my search for that didn't go so well, probably because I'm a newbie at ASP.NET.